# Why can I not view an updated count for a variable with console.log in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, console.log

I currently have this code below, it is supposed to emulate a card counting system, in which different characters increment/decrement the count when passed. The code below runs successfully, but when I attempt console.log(cc(2,3,4,5,6);  it returns 1 Bet, when I know the code runs 5 Bet, as those characters should increment the count, yet console.log does not return the accurate count, I assume this is due to scope? But I would like if someone could explain why count isn't accurately returned.

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  switch(card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count += 1;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      count += 0;
      break;
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count -= 1;
      break;
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet";
  } 
  else {
    return count + " Hold";
  }

}


cc(2,3,4,5,6); \\ returns 5 Bet
console.log(cc(2,3,4,5,6)); \\ returns 2 Bet
```

Comment: You're trying to pass five parameters into a function that only takes one, so the rest are ignored.

Comment: Also, count is not a function level variable. Its value changes whenever you call cc.

Comment: Actually, it *should* log "2 Bet" since you're running it twice and using a global variable, so your code must be different from what you shared here.

Comment: Edited; returns 2.

Comment: you pass 5 argument, but you running/calling  code once only

Comment: I went ahead and changed the params to take 5 inputs and passed in (2,3,4,5,6) to look for any changes but the output is still the same.

Comment: i added answer, check it that what u need

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 0;
const bet = card => {
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count += 1;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      count += 0;
      break;
    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      count -= 1;
      break;
  }
};
function cc(...moves) {
  moves.forEach(bet);
  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet";
  } else {
    return count + " Hold";
  }
}

console.log(cc(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)); // returns 5 Bet
console.log(cc(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)); // returns 10 Bet
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems.

First, your count need to start at zero every time you call `cc()`. Because you have declared `count` outside the function, its values is preserved between calls to `cc()`. By declaring it inside the function, it's initialized to zero before it starts counting the card values.

(Unless you want to continue to the previous count, in which case you should keep it declared outside the function)

Second, your function only accepts one argument. You need to make it accept a list of arguments. This can be done simply with the spread operator `...`. Then you need to loop through each card value and do the count.

```js
function cc(...cards) { // accept a list of card values as arguments.
  let count = 0

  for (const card of cards) { // loop through all card values.
    switch (card) {
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
      case 5:
      case 6:
        count += 1
        break
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
        count += 0
        break
      case 10:
      case 'J':
      case 'Q':
      case 'K':
      case 'A':
        count -= 1
        break
    }
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    return `${count} Bet`
  }

  return `${count} Hold`
}

cc(2, 3, 4, 5, 6) // returns 5 Bet
console.log(cc(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) // returns 5 Bet
console.log(cc(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) // returns 5 Bet
```

Comment: I understand having to insert count within the function in order to preserve it's value, but why did you change var to let?

Comment: No reason specific to this question. `let` is preferred in modern javascript. See [this for more discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Answer (score 0):

Use `arguments` or splat operator to get all arguments passed and then loop it:

```js
function cc(...cards) {
  var count = 0;
  var card;

  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    card = cards[i];
    switch (card) {
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
      case 5:
      case 6:
        count += 1;
        break;
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
        count += 0;
        break;
      case 10:
      case 'J':
      case 'Q':
      case 'K':
      case 'A':
        count -= 1;
        break;
    }
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet";
  } else {
    return count + " Hold";
  }
}



cc(2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // returns 5 Bet
console.log(cc(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)); // returns 2 Bet
```